# Django quill editor affecting html video tag

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, quill

So i have a model that collects the description for a course. It is a quill field as shown below:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    description = QuillField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and i have a model form:

```
class SubTopicForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CourseContentSubTopic
        fields = ['description']
```

Anytime i try to render this form in the frontend by doing this:

```
{{form.media}}
{{form.description}}
```

My html video tag stops working. I noticed the problem comes when i add `{{form.media}}` to the html file.

i have tried looking thorough the docs but i have not seen anything that has proven helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Specifically, show the whole template code (including what's in the `<head>` vs. `<body>` tags) and also add your `views.py` file so we can review how you are rendering the template and Quill field(s).